# Multiple NOT EXISTS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, not-exists

I'm having a really hard time trying to understand this statement. Can someone please explain to me how to trace or tell me the order of operations of why I get the return result.

```
SELECT snumber
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM table3
        WHERE table1.snumber = table3.snumber
        AND table2.pnumber = table3.pnumber));

table1        table2      table3
snumber       pnumber     snumber    pnumber
s1            p1          s1         p1
s2            p2          s1         p2
s3            p3          s1         p3
s4                        s2         p1
s5                        s2         p32
                          s3         p1
                          s3         p2
                          s4         p1
                          s4         p2
                          s5         p1
```

The result returns only s1 which I'm not following. As of now, this is my thought process. The bottom level subquery returns false. Which causes the mid-level subquery to not select anything. Since there's nothing there the top level is true. This would cause the top level to select everything in table 1.

I've looked all over the place for examples of this, but I can't seem to find anything. I really appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the query is looking for values in `table1` where there doesn't exist a value in `table2` where the combination of `table1.snumber` and `table2.pnumber` doesn't exist in `table3`. So, basically it wants all values in `table1` where there is a row in `table3` which pairs that `snumber` with every `pnumber` in `table2`.

Another, perhaps easier to understand, way of writing the query is using `JOIN`s and counting the number of rows in the output. The `HAVING` clause checks that the number of rows for the given `snumber` in the `JOIN` result is the same as the total number of rows in `table2`, i.e. an entry exists in `table3` for each combination of that `snumber` and the `pnumber` values in `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.snumber
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.snumber = t1.snumber
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.pnumber = t3.pnumber
GROUP BY t1.snumber
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
```

Output (for both queries)

```
snumber
s1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/310be3/6)